# How to fix black screen output in OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am experiencing a black screen in my project using OpenGL and C++. I am in need of assistance as to where I went wrong rendering a red triangle to the screen.

I have tried checking for errors in the vertex and fragment shader.

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

unsigned int CreateShader(int type, const string shaderSource) {
    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    const char *src = shaderSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE) {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char *message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, length, &length, message);
        cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex shader " : "fragment shader ") << endl;
        cout << message << endl;
    }


    return shader;
}

unsigned int CreateProgram(const string vertexShader, const string fragmentShader) {
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();

    unsigned int vs = CreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    return program;

}

int main() {

    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "window", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        cout << "Glew initialization Failed! " << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    float positions[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
    };

    cout << "Made By Rial Seebran" << endl;
    cout << glfwGetVersionString() << endl;


    unsigned int VAO;
    unsigned int VBO;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    const string vertexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f);\n"
        "}\n";

    const string fragmentShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "void main() {\n"
        "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int program = CreateProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(program);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting a red triangle drawn at the coordinates specified with a blueish background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter to [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) has to be the primitive type.
It has to be `GL_TRIANGLES` rather than `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`:

<s>`glDrawArrays(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 3);`</s>
`glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`

The OpenGL enumerator constant `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is not an an accepted value for this parameter and will cause an `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error (The error can be get by [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml)).

---

When the clip space coordinate is transformed to normalized device space, then the `x`,  `y` and `z` component is divided by the `w` component. 
This means the `w` component of `gl_Position` has to be set 1.0 rather the 0.0:

<s>`gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f);`</s>
`gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);`

---

Glew can enable additional extensions by `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`. See the [GLEW documentation](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) which says:

> GLEW obtains information on the supported extensions from the graphics driver. Experimental or pre-release drivers, however, might not report every available extension through the standard mechanism, in which case GLEW will report it unsupported. To circumvent this situation, the `glewExperimental` global switch can be turned on by setting it to `GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit()`, which ensures that all extensions with valid entry points will be exposed.

```cpp
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if ( glewInit() != GLEW_OK ) {
    cout << "Glew initialization Failed! " << endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
```